How to use a selected file in javascript function in my Blazor Server App?
In my Blazor Server App the user can select a File from his local drive.
Now this file should be analysed locally in Javascript and the results should be send back to Blazor.
Calling Javascript functions is not the problem, but I have problems to use the file in Javascript. On the C# part it is a IBrowserFile.
I need to do this because the files are very big, so I need to prevent unecessary uploads. On the javascript side I use Mediainfo.js to analyse the file.
I am new to Blazor Server, but as I understand this, the C# code runns completly on the server, so the solutions I found did not work, because they always do some file conversion in C# and that mees the file has to be uploaded fist.
It would be great to get a solution for this.

If you used c# code to get the file IBrowserFile, the whole file will have to be uploaded to server because c# code will be processed in server. So you have to get the file directly without c#. Then return the data to c# when javascript process finished. Such as following return the filesize as processed data.
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<input type="file" id="fileInput"  />
<br />
<button @onclick="ProcessData">Prosss Data</button>
<br />
FileSize:@FileSize bytes

<script>
   
    async function processFile(Id){
        const fileInput = document.getElementById(Id);
        var fileSize = fileInput.files[0].size;
        return fileSize;
    }
</script>

@code{
    private int FileSize = 0;
    private async Task ProcessData()
    {
        FileSize=await JS.InvokeAsync<int>("processFile","fileInput");
    }
}


Thank you for your answer. In my case there is much more to do before upload, so I changed my whole project from Blazor Server App to Blazor Web App, so the main part can run on server and the upload part runs as webassably direct on client side.
